# How can I get the number of trainable parameters of a model in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am setting `trainable=False` in all my layers, implemented through the `Model` API, but I want to verify whether that is working. `model.count_params()` returns the total number of parameters, but is there any way in which I can get the total number of trainable parameters, other than looking at the last few lines of `model.summary()`?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no better way than `model.summary()`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
from keras import backend as K

trainable_count = int(
    np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.trainable_weights)]))
non_trainable_count = int(
    np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.non_trainable_weights)]))

print('Total params: {:,}'.format(trainable_count + non_trainable_count))
print('Trainable params: {:,}'.format(trainable_count))
print('Non-trainable params: {:,}'.format(non_trainable_count))
```

The above snippet can be discovered in the end of [`layer_utils.print_summary()`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/d1ad18377011664e1e643dedafb35eb07de57a7f/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L8-L129) definition, which [`summary()`](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/7dcd2982b2faf08018d0fe22426834072a4ddb58/keras/engine/topology.py#L2640-L2658) is calling.

---

Edit: more recent version of Keras has a helper function [`count_params()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f17712cfcbd14c19a1f7cb1dbb9be41f2dbba184/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/layer_utils.py#L95-L109) for this purpose:

```
from keras.utils.layer_utils import count_params

trainable_count = count_params(model.trainable_weights)
non_trainable_count = count_params(model.non_trainable_weights)
```

Comment: Note that batchnormalization parameters are not counted as `trainable` even though they are Variables that change during training.

Comment: If you are using TensorFlow 2, the `count_params` function is now found at `from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.layer_utils import count_params`

Comment: Or just `sum(count_params(layer) for layer in model.trainable_weights)` for a bit more readability... it's not clear to me what the call to `set` accomplishes.

Answer (score 18):

For **TensorFlow 2.0**:

```
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(w) for w in model.trainable_weights])
non_trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(w) for w in model.non_trainable_weights])

print('Total params: {:,}'.format(trainable_count + non_trainable_count))
print('Trainable params: {:,}'.format(trainable_count))
print('Non-trainable params: {:,}'.format(non_trainable_count))
```

Answer (score 1):

For tensorflow.keras this works for me. Its from the tensorflow github code for the function print_layer_summary_with_connections() in layer_utils.py

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.util import object_identity

def count_params(weights):
    return int(sum(np.prod(p.shape.as_list())
      for p in object_identity.ObjectIdentitySet(weights)))

if hasattr(model, '_collected_trainable_weights'):
    trainable_count = count_params(model._collected_trainable_weights)
else:
    trainable_count = count_params(model.trainable_weights)

print (trainable_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution:

```
trainable_params = sum(prod(w.shape) for w in model.trainable_weights)
```

(requires `from math import prod`).

Answer (score -4):

Another way to count trainable parameters is:

```
model.count_params()
```

Comment: No, it's the total number of parameters, trainable and not.