# Is there a way to know how many parameters does an object detection model have, in tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I train different models with tensor object detection (TFOD) API and I would like to know how many parameters are trained for a given model.

I run faster RCNN, SSD, RFCN and also with different image resolution, I would like to have a way to know how many parameters are trained. Is there a way to do that?

I have tried answers found here [How to count total number of trainable parameters in a tensorflow model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160940/how-to-count-total-number-of-trainable-parameters-in-a-tensorflow-model) with no luck.

Here is the code I added line 103 of `model_main.py`:

```
print("Training {} parameters".format(np.sum([np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list()) for v in tf.trainable_variables()]))
```

I think the problem is that I do not access the tf.Session() the TFOD is running, hence my code always return 0.0 parameters (although training strats just fine and train, hopefully, millions of parameters), and I don't know how to solve that issue.

Comment: What do you mean how many parameters are trained? Do you simply mean how many parameters are in your model?

Comment: @BlueRineS Yes, I need to know how many parameters are in the model

Comment: Hey man, it would be pretty useful if you could post some of the parameters like for ssd, faster rcnn, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the export_inference_graph.py, the script also analyzes your model, and counts parameters and FLOPS (if possible).
If looks like this:

```
_TFProfRoot (--/# total params)
  FeatureExtractor (--/# params)
  ...
  WeightSharedConvolutionalBoxPredictor (--/# params)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

TFOD API used `tf.estimator.Estimator` to train and evaluate. The `Estimator` object provided function to get all the variables, `Estimator.get_variable_names()` ([reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_names)).

You can add this line `print(estimator.get_variable_names())` after `estimator.train_and_evaluate()` ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/5175b7e69c74b13405afa26761d79a21ff1621ef/research/object_detection/model_main.py#L105)).

You will see all variable names printed after the training is completed. To see the results faster, you can train for just 1 step.

Comment: Is it the answer you were looking for? Or I answered it wrong?