# Monitoring weight sparsity during training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I wonder if it is possible to monitor the percentage of nonzero weights of the full network (not just a layer) during training?

For example, I use

```
optim = AdagradDAOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(my_loss)
```

and

```
for i in range(10):
  sess = tf.Session()
  loss, _ = sess.run([my_loss, optim])
```

and I would like to print the ratio of the number nonzero weights over the number of all weights after every iteration. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following code calculate the number of nonzero weights.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tvars = sess.run(tf.trainable_variables())
nonzero_parameters = np.sum([np.count_nonzero(var) for var in tvars])
```

Here shows how to calculate the total number of weights: [How to count total number of trainable parameters in a tensorflow model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160940/how-to-count-total-number-of-trainable-parameters-in-a-tensorflow-model).