# Recording weight norm during training with TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I am training a neural network using tensorflow and I would like to monitor the L2-norm of some of the layers.
I found how to do this in tensorflow 1, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130434/monitoring-weight-sparsity-during-training), but I could not find a way to do the same in tensorflow 2. I wonder how can I do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2 provides compat version of Tensorflow 1.
Please find the below code for computing nonzero weights

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#Replace tf.trainable_variables() with tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables
tvars = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
nonzero_parameters = np.sum([np.count_nonzero(var) for var in tvars])
```