# How to convert TF object detection models to tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there a way to convert TF object detection models from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md) to tf.keras? If not, how can I get the total number of variables in the model?

Comment: have you looked into their collab ? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, at least I was able to count the number of weights. But I'm not sure I'm doing well. I'm running a MobileNet V2 SSD FPNLite 320x320 model and I get around 2.6 million of parameters while in the MobileNet paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.04381.pdf they report a value of 4.3 million for SSDLite (and I also have the FPN subnet).

Comment: Hi @balu ! Could you check this thread for getting number of parameters from trainable_variables.                                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160940/how-to-count-total-number-of-trainable-parameters-in-a-tensorflow-model