# Number of parameters of a TFHub model

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-hub

I would like to count the number of parameters of a Object Detection model loaded from TensorFlow Hub, for example https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2.
I've tried this:

```
hub_model = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2")
print(len(hub_model.signatures['serving_default'].variables))
```

But the output is not very readable and I'm not even sure if it's correct.
I've also tried this way:

```
malli = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/ssd_mobilenet_v2/2")
print("Thickness of the model:", len(malli.weights))
```

But it returns just an empty list [] of length 0.

It would be nice to be able to use the Keras summary() method on these models, but it cannot be called on a KerasLayer, so would incorporating this layer into a model with Keras.Sequential work?

Comment: You could try hub.load() followed by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38160940/how-to-count-total-number-of-trainable-parameters-in-a-tensorflow-model

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that counts total number of parameters for a checkpoint file: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py

```
$ python inspect_checkpoint.py --file_name=/checkpoint/file/name --all_tensors
```